# Query to get items due in the next 7 days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have an `insurance_end` column in my table, which is a `datetime` value.

So with today's date being: `2015-02-20`, I want to retrieve items that are due to end in the next 7 days.

**Sample Data:**

```
insurance_end
=======================
2017-02-13 00:00:00.000
2016-02-13 00:00:00.000
2015-02-13 00:00:00.000
2015-02-14 00:00:00.000
2015-02-20 00:00:00.000
2015-02-28 00:00:00.000
2015-02-28 00:00:00.000
2015-02-04 00:00:00.000
2015-02-13 00:00:00.000
2015-02-01 00:00:00.000
2015-02-10 00:00:00.000
2013-02-09 00:00:00.000
```

**Desired output would be:**

```
insurance_end
=======================    
2015-02-14 00:00:00.000
2015-02-20 00:00:00.000
2015-02-13 00:00:00.000
```

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT* 
FROM customer_profile
WHERE DATEADD(dd, -7, insurance_end) <= CAST(insurance_end AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: can you add sample data and expected output.

Comment: result displays so many results data however not displaying dates between column - 7 days and column

Comment: Do you want to find only particular `insurance_end` date and -7 days from that date.

Comment: yes my friend may you please write code example

Comment: please check my question thanks @NoDisplayName

Comment: Note clear: I have been looking for 2 dates between one column - 7 days one column datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to show records where the insurance is ending within the next 7 days.

Just use `GETDATE()` to get today's date and subtract 7 days to get the date of 7 days prior. `CONVERT` to `DATE` to take off the time portion.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS TodaysDate, 
       CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 7) AS TodayMinus7
```

This will give you:

```
TodaysDate    TodayMinus7
==========================
2015-02-20    2015-02-13
```

You can then compare this value to your `insurance_end` values:

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32a12/3)

**MS SQL Server Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_profile
    ([insurance_end] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO customer_profile
    ([insurance_end])
VALUES
    ('2015-02-13 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-02-14 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-02-20 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-02-28 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-02-28 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-02-04 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-02-13 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-02-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-02-10 00:00:00'),
    ('2013-02-09 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query To Get Desired Output**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_profile
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() -7) <= insurance_end 
  AND insurance_end <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

You could also change the `WHERE` clause to use `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE insurance_end BETWEEN 
      CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() -7) AND CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32a12/3/0)**:

```
|                   INSURANCE_END |
|---------------------------------|
| February, 13 2015 00:00:00+0000 |
| February, 14 2015 00:00:00+0000 |
| February, 20 2015 00:00:00+0000 |
| February, 13 2015 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM insurance
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),insurance_end)=-7;
```

[Fiddle demo for reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55d75/7)

Comment: insurance_end -7 and insurance_end is it so ?

Comment: @OmerIpek Sorry I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: I want to get  between insurance_end' days before 7 days and insurance_end

Comment: @OmerIpek:Updated my answer too.